# Average returns way too big number (two variables)

Tags: javascript, html

When I divide two diffrent variables, I get this returned:

```
1.4007342235591407
```

but what I want is just two decimals, like this:

```
1.40
```

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('place').innerHTML = meter / seler;
```

Comment: Awww, I was expecting something like `average(1,2,3) = 167`...

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my case it was two variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`<number>.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```
document.getElementById('place').innerHTML = (meter / seler).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Searched up on Google now, but what I found was outdated and a harder way of doing it.